# Is there a simple histogram function?

Tags: python, matlab, histogram

For data `diffs07` and `diffs14`, in `Matlab` I can get the x and y coordinates of the binned data by simply using:

```
[ys07, xs07] = hist(-log10(diffs07), 250);
[ys14, xs14] = hist(-log10(diffs14), 250);
```

In `Python`, however, I can't find a straightforward way so I am using:

```
xs_diffs = np.linspace(0, 17, 250)
dx = xs_diffs[1]-xs_diffs[2]
ys07 = []
ys14 = []
for x in xs_diffs:
    ys07.append( len( [ ty for ty in diffs07 if (-np.log10(ty)-dx/2.0 < x and -np.log10(ty) < x+dx/2.0) ] ) ) 
    ys14.append( len( [ ty for ty in diffs14 if (-np.log10(ty)-dx/2.0 < x and -np.log10(ty) < x+dx/2.0) ] ) ) 

plt.plot(xs_diffs, ys07, 'r.', xs_diffs, ys14, 'b.')
plt.show()
```

But this takes quite a long time compared to the `Matlab` code. Is there a straightforward (and faster!) way to do this in `Python`?

Comment: Pandas has a hist function.

Comment: as does numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Answer (score 5):

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(diffs07,bins=250)
```

for automatic selection of bins (the Matlab equivalent of your first statement). Alternatively,

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(diffs07,bins=np.linspace(0,17,250))
```

should be used if you want to specify the range of the bins used as per your initial attempt.

Matplotlib also has the very helpful `plt.hist` for immediate plotting, again with the option of automatic or set bins.

Comment: for binning I'd still use `np.linspace`. With `bins=250` you get 250 bins from the min value to the max value in `diffs07` which might not be equal to 0 and 17 at all. So: `np.histogram(diffs07,bins=np.linspace(0,17,250))`

Comment: Thanks @Swier, good point, I've added that in case they want to fix where the bins are.